# How to transition between floors with 2" height difference?

Tags: basement, flooring

Renovating floors in concrete slab basement. After tearing up existing floor and fixing drywall, new floor was placed with insulation, OBS, padding, and vinyl. The other rooms are carpet directly on the concrete. This has caused a 2" height difference where they meet (as shown below). The other issue is that this joining is at the bottom of a staircase, which means I can't just raise the floor to match the new height, or it will mess with the offset of the steps. The way I see it, I need to try and create a custom floor reducer/strip to transition in the door threshold.

[image: Floor Layout]

[image: Floor Gap]

Comment: Will probably need a long low slope ramp type, 6 or 8 inch wide for comfort.  Maybe 4 inch wide for non comfort.

Comment: "need to try and create a custom floor reducer/strip to transition in the door threshold" - yep. Gotta rip something on a table saw and then still have all of your fingers. Then you need a transition strip on top of that transition, or that flooring to be flush cut straight as an arrow. - The one time I had this 2" problem, it got a ramp 2 *feet* long; still not comfortable.

Comment: Oh, looking at it backwards. Any transition you do will violate the landing space. You have to put the transition in that room. Which is a garbage idea.

Comment: Sorry but this should have been planned out from the start - you now have a unfixable tripping hazard. Paint a yellow strip and put a "watch your step" sign on the door.

Answer (score 2):

Any solution will require raising the floor all the way across the stairway (so that the last step isn't sloping to the side).

If you do that simply by extending the new floor across the width of the stairs, the pink room will end up rectangular and the transition area will be within the pink room and will end up having to be quite large so that people don't trip or stumble when going up or down it.

---

But there is a simpler way.
You could instead do it by raising the floor at the bottom of the stairs to the same level as the bottom step.

The transition would then be a large platform which will feel like part of the stairs.
The step going down to the pink room would be 2 inches higher than the step going down to the blue room, but that's not nearly as bad as a single step that is 2 inches high.

Whether a single step like that meets the building code in your area, I can't say, but I *have* seen at least one house with a similar setup.

---

But really, the correct solution is to bite the bullet and "do it right" by raising the pink room's floor by 2 inches.

Comment: nope, you get 3/8ths of an inch variance between *all* steps and landings.

Comment: Can't raise the pink room's floor by 2 inches. That's 1-5/8s too much variance. ""do it right" by raising the pink room's floor by 2 inches [and then build a new staircase!]" - yeah, no; that's why tile is what goes on a basement slab, and for many other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

A high contrast color transition might be the best solution. Any ramp will act as a tilted bottom step for the stairs.